# gulp-htmlmin close automaticly the tags

Tags: html, gulp

I'm having a problem with `gulp-htmlmin`.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="test">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

With the closing of the div (`</div>`) deliberately not added.

The compiled HTML code, is:

```
<div class="test"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
```

I wish I do not automatically close the tags, ie the result is:

```
<div class="test"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you want malformed html?

Comment: @DerekMT12 Is for PHP/HTML files. Should I include a `header` and a `footer`, where a tag starts in `header` which is then closed in the `footer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem. In `gulpfile.js` add the option for htmlmin: `includeAutoGeneratedTags: false`.

For example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

var htmlminOptions = {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    includeAutoGeneratedTags: false
};

...

gulp.task('minify:html', function() {
    gulp.src('**/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin(htmlminOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/dest');
});
```

For more see: [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier)